# How do I know the hexadecimal value in memory of a variable using the VS debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

How do I know the hexadecimal value in memory of a 32-bit floating point variable using the VS debugger?

Comment: I tested the answer below in Visual Studio debugger and it works.

Comment: You can also right click e.g. in the watch window and in the context menu select to show numbers as hexadecimal.

Answer (score 0):

Add a watch for `*(uint32_t*)&f,h` where `f` is the variable you'd like to inspect